# Can we run multiple Ajax Submit Buttons on one custom form with different ajax callbacks?

Tags: 8

Because In my case, the first ajax button works however next doesn't and it reloads the page.

```
    $form['step_1']['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => 'Search',
        '#name' => 'first_submit',
        '#submit' => array([$this, 'first_submit']),
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => '::firstCallback',
            'wrapper' => 'wrap-callback',
            'method' => 'replace',
            'effect' => 'fade',
            'event' => 'click'
        )
    );


    $form['step_2']['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => 'Continue',
        '#name' => 'second_submit',
        '#submit' => array([$this, 'sectond_callback']),
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => '::secondCallback',
            'wrapper' => 'wrap-callback',
            'method' => 'replace',
            'effect' => 'fade',
            'event' => 'click'
        )
    );
```

Comment: Get ridoff the `#submit` line. I don't think thats a valid key.

Comment: Inpect html, check that `wrap-callback` div exists before you click second button.

Comment: @NoSssweat #submit is indeed valid and is used to define a callback.